# Call a function on Module Install

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

How to call a function or execute a code on module install only (Not update)?
Is there a specific function for that ?

I want to execute this code on module install:

```
all_countries = self.env['res.country'].search([])
for country in all_countries:
   _logger.error(country.name)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a `data` file.

1. Add the data file to your __openerp__ file
2. Create the data file with the `noupdate="1"` flag

   - This indicates the code should be run once, then never again
   - It will run upon installation, or if the module is already installed, then it will the next time the module is upgraded.
3. Define the `function` element in your data file to trigger the appropriate python method

You can see the documentation [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/data.html#function) for details, but the end result looks something like this:

**__openerp__.py**

```
{
    ...
    'data': [
        ...
        'data/data.xml',
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

**/data/data.xml**

```
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <function model="res.country" name="method_name"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**/models/country.py**

```
from openerp import models
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ResCountry(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.country'

    @api.model
    def method_name(self):
        for country in self.search([]):
           _logger.error(country.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a workaround to run arbitrary code at install/uninstall time, that is [described here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/execute-query-when-installing-addon-86598#answer-86638) in details. In your case suitable function to write your code in is a `create` method from the proposed workaround.

Comment: The code you linked is best if you need to run a function during install **and** uninstall, but it is more than necessary if the code only needs to run once. The [function](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/data.html#function) element in a data file, combined with `noupdate="1"` easily achieves the desired effect.

Comment: sure, I've used the `function` tag in my practice as well, but as you noted it can handle only installation case. and  a small note to your comment: option I referred to can handle "install  AND/OR uninstall" scenario, not just "install AND uninstall" as you're free to omit one of the `create` or `unlink` methods if you do not need one.